# FASM функции для работы с файлами, добавление импорта в DLL

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Есть готовая DLL; как можно в нее добавить несколько инструкций с созданием, проверкой существования, переименованием файлов, но при этом в импорте походу этих функций нет. Через Олли я на точку входа поставил переход в конец кода (где среди пустых байтов разместил свой код) файл создает, через `_lcreat`, а как проверить существование файла, если нет импорта `GetFileAttribytes`, `MoveFile` тоже не импортируется, или я неправильно или не там их ищу. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: 1. Добавить несколько машинных команд в dll? Это именно то, что Вам надо? В какое место dll Вы хотите их вставить?
2. Кто такой Олли? Википедия говорит, что это трюк в скейтборде. При чём тут dll?
3. Далее вообще непереводимо. Подозреваю, что этот вопрос не для меня, но для уверенности хотелось бы получить некоторые пояснения.

Comment: Олли - Olly Debbuger - отладчик дизассемблер.
Свои команды пишу в конец файла используя выравнивание по секциям(которое дает не мало пустых байт) при этом на начало, тоесть на адрес с которого происходить загрузка, я ставлю передачу управаления на свой код, сдесь все нормально, мой код отработал передал управление обратно, и ДЛЛ инициализировалась.
Но если в импорте ДЛЛ нету функции как ее можно использовать. Нашел в импорте LoadLibraryA(LoadLibraryW) и GetProcAddress. Но незнаю как их использовать.

Тойсть мне необходимо или загрузить библиотеку в Длл и добавить функцию, или расширить импорт

Comment: Неувидев последнего сообщения от cy6erGn0m, сильно намучался, там действительно NULL а не адрес функции, GetFileAttributesA нашлась легко. Странно но при использовании LoadLibraryA и GetProcAddress находилась функция, но библиотека дальше этого не шла, приложение ее неиспользовало, и выдавало ошибку, но при этом атрибуты файла влияли на выбор текста файла, который я использовал для проверки, тойсть если файл существовал то мне так и писало, если нет, писало не существует, значит GetFileAttributesA выполняла свою функцию, только с чем может быть связан последующий вылет библиотеки

Comment: Только что удалил запись в файл
PUSH opengl32.5F2C4FED
CALL kernel32._lcreat

так все нормально, но неизвестно нашло или нет. возможно это из-за _lcreat

Answer (score 1):

"Нашел в импорте LoadLibraryA(LoadLibraryW) и GetProcAddress. Но не знаю, как их использовать." - это то, что вам поможет. С помощью [LoadLibraryA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) загружаете библиотеку, а с помощью GetProcAddress получаете указатель на функцию, которая вам нужна. Например, [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) находится в kernel32.dll. Ну так и укажите её в [LoadLibraryA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) и получите HANDLE библиотеки. А зная HANDLE модуля и имя "GetFileAttributes" находите адрес функции GetFileAttributes. А потом делаете call туда, заполнив предварительно стек нужными параметрами.

**UPD**

Примеров даже на асме полно  ([Вот, например](http://www.opensc.ws/asm/9299-fasm-getprocaddress-example.html)), не говоря уже о примерах на C/C++.

Comment: Вот именно реализацию я и непонял, мне б пример, был бы очень благодарен. Я пробовал загрузить библиотеку, возвращаемое значение LoadLibraryA передал в GetProcAddress вместе с именем искомой функции, но полученное от нее значение выдало ошибку при Call тойсть стек я предварительно заполнил данными.

Comment: Значит неверно заполнили стек.. если только GetProcAddress != NULL

Comment: А можно пример кода, для наглядности.

Comment: но GetProcAddress = NULL я думаю только если функция ненайдена, а ведь имя функции как и библиотеки переданы верно, тогда в чем может быть причина

Comment: Не гадайте. Узнайте точно.

Comment: А я подозреваю, что там экспортируется не GetFileAttributes, а GetFileAttributesA и GetFileAttributesW. Посмотрите список экспорта библиотеки или документацию~